# Trying to get property of non-object in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm using yii framework and I'm new in yii and can't understand the problem in this code, it is giving error in this code and I just attached the image of my code

[image: image1]

and when I just try to `echo '<pre>';print_r($role);echo '</pre>';` it just print code like this

[image: image2]

can't understand why this is giving error.

Comment: please check yii::$app->user->id is getting or not ?

Comment: when I try to print any thing it is showing same at my browser you can see the difference between image1 and image2... look at the images carefully.... at line no 43 in second image...

Comment: `->asArray()->one()` shoud couse that, I guess `asArray` returns an array you shoud stop chaining there. Line 44 checks array length

Comment: nothing is working when I try to `print_r` or `echo` something it is showing the php code at my browser...

Comment: Line 42 ending `..."'")->asArray();//->one();`  and than `print_r` will work

Comment: not working I tried again... it is showing php code again...

Comment: before line 42 print using print_r() and die() your code

Comment: it is not showing any error...

Comment: @user3833682 please post also the related portion of code. so i can post and eventually ansewer without rewrite your code..

Comment: can you add me to chat room...

Answer (score 0):

Please check 'AuthAssignment' table has 'item_name' and 'user_id' columns. Also, please check users table has column name 'id'.

The error is appearing here due to wrong column name being used in AR.

Hope that will help to solve your issue.

Comment: yes it has `item_name` and `user_id` fields...

Comment: Can you please post 'AuthAssignment' model code (up to rules ) ? Also, please post source code line #42.

Comment: can you add me chat room please...

Comment: I am in chat room (PHP), you can join there.http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: I just posted my code in chatroom...

Comment: User `The Code` are you there???